# Most optimum way to rename XML tags using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML file:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<consentException fpmlVersion="5-6" >
    <header>
        <messageId messageIdScheme="www.test.com">LH_msf_id</messageId>
        <inReplyTo messageIdScheme="">2424234243</inReplyTo><!-- message Id of entering party  -->
        <sentBy>test</sentBy>
        <sendTo>SEF1</sendTo>
        <creationTimestamp>2010-09-09T10:00:00-00:00</creationTimestamp>
    </header>
    <correlationId correlationIdScheme="">SEF_correlationId</correlationId>
    <reason>
        <reasonCode>3500001</reasonCode>
        <description>Invalid Currency ABC</description>
    </reason>
    <reason>
        <reasonCode>3500043</reasonCode>
        <description>Organization XYZ is not defined</description>
    </reason>
</consentException>
```

Here is my XSLT File:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="consentException/header/sentBy"> 
  <Hello><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></Hello>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now here, the XSLT code replaces the tag in the xml file: (the Hello tag)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><consentException fpmlVersion="5-6">
    <header>
        <messageId messageIdScheme="www.test.com/">LH_msf_id</messageId>
        <inReplyTo messageIdScheme="">2424234243</inReplyTo><!-- message Id of entering party  -->
        <Hello>Test</Hello>
        <sendTo>SEF1</sendTo>
        <creationTimestamp>2010-09-09T10:00:00-00:00</creationTimestamp>
    </header>
    <correlationId correlationIdScheme="">SEF_correlationId</correlationId>
    <reason>
        <reasonCode>3500001</reasonCode>
        <description>Invalid Currency ABC</description>
    </reason>
    <reason>
        <reasonCode>3500043</reasonCode>
        <description>Organization XYZ is not defined</description>
    </reason>
</consentException>
```

But if I wanted you replace ALL the tags in the XML file, rather than specifying each and every tag, Is there a better way to do it?

I'm not sure about this but if there was a file which contains the XML tags and what XML tags have to be replaced with, can it by some way to reference the file with XSLT code?

I'm trying to find the most optimum way to complete this task.
Note: Tag replacement HAVE to be done with XSLT code only

**UPDATE**

Here is what the final XML should look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<consentException fpmlVersion="5-6" >
    <header>
        <FPHdMsgID FPHdMsgIDScheme="www.test.com">LH_msf_id</FPHdMsgID>
        <inReplyTo messageIdScheme="">2424234243</inReplyTo><!-- message Id of entering party  -->
        <FPHdSentBy>Traiana</FPHdSentBy>
        <FPHdSentTo>SEF1</FPHdSentTo>
        <FPHdCreateTime>2010-09-09T10:00:00-00:00</FPHdCreateTime>
    </header>
    <FPCorID FPCorIDSch="">SEF_correlationId</FPCorID>
    <reason>
        <FPRsnCode>3500001</FPRsnCode>
        <FPRsnDesc>Invalid Currency ABC</FPRsnDesc>
    </reason>
    <reason>
        <FPRsnCode>3500043</FPRsnCode>
        <description>Organization XYZ is not defined</description>
    </reason>
</consentException>
```

Comment: If you'd like to replace the names of all elements - what should their names be replaced with? What would the output look like?

Answer (score 0):

> if there was a file which contains the XML tags and what XML tags have
>   to be replaced with, can it by some way to reference the file with
>   XSLT code?

Yes, but it would certainly **not** be "the most optimum way to complete this task" because it would introduce an unnecessary (and rather costly) step into process. This *could* be a good approach if you had to change the rename mappings from time to time, and didn't want to modify the master XSLT document in the process. Otherwise it's best to have a template for each rename. XSLT is naturally verbose, get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

Define the mapping file like this:

renaming.xml

```
<rename>
  <rename old="foo" new="bar"/>
  <rename old="fox" new="box"/>
</rename>
```

Then write a 'meta-stylesheet' like this:

```
<xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix='a' result-prefix="xsl"/>
<xsl:template match="rename">
  <a:template match="{@old}">
    <a:element name="{@new}">
      <a:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <a:apply-templates/>
    </a:element>
  </a:template>
</xsl:template>
```

Run this meta-stylesheet against rename.xml, and you produce an XSLT stylesheet with one template rule per element name, that can be run against any source document and performs the renaming.

I've left a few details out, of course, like handling elements whose name isn't in the renaming file, or handling namespaces. But the task is easy enough.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, i did as you said but i get this error.
The prefix "a" for element "a:template" is not bound.

Comment: Well, I did say I'd left a few details out. I like to point people in the right direction rather than holding their hand all the way to the destination. If you don't know how to declare a namespace in your stylesheet, you need to do some reading.